# Spring ResourceSupport - return child class resource object based on type of the member

Tags: java, spring, rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I have a resource called `MyResource`

```
public class MyResource extends ResourceSupport {
    protected final Stuff stuff;

    public EventResource(Stuff stuff) {
        this.stuff= stuff;
    }
    public String getUserId() { return stuff.getUserId(); }
}
```

The catch here is that `Stuff` has been extended in another class called `TestStuff`, which has an additional member `testId`. So I created another Resource called `TestResource` that extends `MyResource` and has a getter method to return `testId`.

```
public class TestResource extends MyResource{
    protected final TestStuff testStuff;

    public EventResource(Stuff stuff) {
        super(stuff)
        this.stuff= (TestStuff)stuff;
    }

    public String getTestId() { return stuff.getTestId(); }

}
```

There is also another class just like `TestResource`, called `SampleResource` that has a `SampleStuff` object derived from the `Stuff` class and it has an additional `sampleId`.

The problem here is I would like Spring to automatically use the appropriate Resource type based on the type of object stuff in the `MyResource` class.

So here, it would be returning a `TestResource` if my stuff object is of type `TestStuff` or a `SampleResource` if my stuff object is of type `SampleStuff`.
I believe there should be an automatic way of doing this, but couldn't find it. If anyone could help me with this, I will appreciate it.

Comment: sounds like you're asking for a ResourceFactory..just build one

Comment: I don't understand why you created an additional resource.

Comment: Then what else do I need to do to reflect `TestStuff`?

Comment: If your last comment was directed at me: Polymorphism is handled by Jackson. It's done by  adding [@JsonTypeInfo](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html)

Comment: @zeroflagL Thanks, but there's no property to these resources. What do I specify there?

`@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include= JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = ???)`

Comment: `property` would be the property in the resulting  `JSON` output. You can name it whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks, but there's no property in the resulting JSON. All we have are objects of classes `Stuff` and `TestStuff`